# Django abstract model with indices, constraints and permissions: attributes are not inherited by sub classes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I am using Django 3.2

I have the following models:

#### app1

```
class IsPinnable(models.Model):
    is_pinned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pin_after_expiry_day_count = models.DurationField(default=0)    

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['is_pinned' ]),
        ]
    


class IsModeratable(models.Model):
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    target_count_trigger = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    positive_pass_count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    negative_pass_count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
 
    # Other fields and methods ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # TODO: Sanity check on pass_count and trigger sizes
        # ...
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        permissions = (
                       ("moderate_item", "can moderate item"),
                       ("reset_moderation", "can (re)moderate a moderated item"),
                      )
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['approved' ]),
        ]    

    class MyComponent(IsPinnable, IsModeratable):
        # some fields and methods ...

        class Meta(IsPinnable.Meta, IsModeratable.Meta):
            abstract = True
            
            # other stuff ...
```

#### app2

```
from app1.models import MyComponent

class Foo(MyComponent):
    # some fields and methods ...
    class Meta(MyComponent.Meta):
        abstract = False
```

Now, I know that abstract model classes are not created in the database - so I was initially expecting Django to throw an exception when I attempted to `makemigrations` - to my surprise, I was able to `makemigrations` && `migrate`.

However, when I inspected the database (via psql), I found that although table `app2_foo` had all the fields described in it's parent class, the indixes were not being carried up from the parent classes as the [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance) would seem to suggest.

What am I missing?, and how do I get the indices, constrains and permissions defined in parent classes to propagate to sub classes?

Comment: Did you redefine the index and other attributes in `MyComponent.Meta` that you think are not showing up? If you didn't the index for `is_pinned` should be present (the one for `approved` won't be there as in the MRO `IsPinnable.Meta` would come first)

Comment: My first response would be to say "No, I didn't redefine the index" - but then it depends on what you mean by "redefining the index" - if you mean, did the subclass have an Indexes attribute (but different index name) - then "Yes", but that would be a rather onerous restriction - meaning that if a parent class defines an index, then **NO** subclass is required to define other indexes.

Regarding the order issue you mentioned, are you saying it is not possible to inherit indices from different classes when using multiple inheritance?

Comment: You expect the indices to get merged, but I'm not sure there's logic in the meta class for that. Either way, unless you need special index behaviour, this is much easier and clearer to implement using `db_index=True` at the field level.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli that is just how multiple inheritance works, inheriting from a class and redefining its attribute which are lists does not mean that these lists will be merged. Neither will the lists of the parent classes be merged. You can do something like `indexes = [...] + IsPinnable.Meta.indexes + IsModeratable.Meta.indexes` if you need such features.

Comment: Interesting gotcha ... Ok, I think the `db_index=True` is cleaner and more explicit - and perfectly solves the index problem. What about unique indices (and composite indices) and permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just normal class inheritance behaviour, take this snippet for instance:

```
class A:
    attr = [1]


class B:
    attr = [2]


class C(A, B):
    pass


print(C.attr) # Outputs: [1]
```

This is because `A` is before `B` in the [Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). If suppose `C` defined `attr = [3]` then the output would have been `[3]`.

You can do something like this in the child class if you need to override those attributes:

```
class MyComponent(IsPinnable, IsModeratable):
    # some fields and methods ...
    
    class Meta(IsPinnable.Meta, IsModeratable.Meta):
        abstract = True
        indexes = [...] + IsPinnable.Meta.indexes + IsModeratable.Meta.indexes # explicitly assign the indexes here
```

> **Note**: Although What you want can be made possible if Django decides to put that logic in the meta class (this is different from
> `Meta` here) of the `Meta`, but I believe that would then require much
> work on their end to merge such attributes and would be backwards
> incompatible and honestly would be a weird feature, what if one
> **doesn't** want those indexes?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I suspected something like this was going on behind the scene (reminds me of the [diamond problem](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html) in C++